# Ignore the thread in Collision Detection in Solidworks

Tags: solidworks

How can I ignore the thread in standard parts in Solidworks (for Example nut with thread) in the collision simulation without deactivating the component? I can disable all the 180 nuts in the list of components, but there has to be a way to solve this problem more elegantly. On the other hand, the collision detection notifies me about a possible collision with components (those that include thread) even before the movement simulation.

Comment: Could you create an alternate configuration for the nut part, that has a larger ID in the model, and then switch to that when required? The nut will not be manufactured/specified from the dimensions in the CAD so the risk associated is minimal.

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick feedback. We also tried that. Unfortunately, even with this step, the collision message can not be hold down.

Comment: With the steps mentioned above, there would be no collision, though? Can you post a screenshot of it detecting a collision once you've adjusted the ID of the nut to not be touching?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It turns out that the thread in the student version can not be isolated. In the full and professional version you can isolate this in the collision test.